# Best approach to handle the POST req when adding n items one after the other

Tags: angular, rest, api, post, rxjs

[image]

With reference to the image, I've a use case where I am adding n items (Range could be from 1 to 5/10/20+ items) which are names of users. I am using Angular UI and RxJS for handling this and wondering what would be the approach to update the backend service, meaning at what point should I be updating the backend service, would that be for each item added or at certain point or would that be when a "Save" or "Submit" action on the overall form that isn't in the picture, but appears on the overall form. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: I think it depends on the user work flow. If there is another save button, you can save it as a whole.  Otherwise you need to make individual requests. In your case you can do it on form submit.

Comment: When we refresh the page, the added users get lost and was wondering what would be an optimal approach to take here without making too many POST requests.

Comment: For that you can use a cookie or browser local-storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a save button then you should save changes only in case of its click. For example user edits records, removes everything and then decides that it was wrong and doesn't click the save button - if he refreshes the page he should get all items again.
Once the save button has been clicked an array of all items should be sent to the backend and the backend adds / updates / deletes records in database.

If you don't have the save button, then in the case of delete button would be nice to have a confirmation to allow the user to change his decision.